# How to make solr phrase search differentiate relative locations of words

Tags: solr

Let's say we have a query "Homepage Content".
And there are two records whose `title` field are (1) "Homepage content" and (2) "content in homepage", respectively.

How to configure solr so that (1) has a higher matching score than (2) for the given query.

(I know it does not make sense to use edismax in this simplified example. But I would like the problem solvers to be aware of the fact that I am using edismax in the real situation.)

Here is my current (extremely simplified) configuration:

**schema.xml**:

```
<field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

**solrconfig.xml**:

```
defType='dismax'
qf="title^2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to use the `pf` argument. It will rank the document higher if the terms are closer together.

Moreover you could use the `ps`  parameter
(Phrase Slop) in order to specify the number of positions that two terms can be apart to match the relevant phrase.

[Here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Thepf(PhraseFields)Parameter) is the link to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with elevate component.

For some query string you can specify which doc to be in the top of result  by using its docID in elevate.xml file, which will be inside conf folder.

example :

`<query text="Homepage">
   <doc id="docID" />  <!-- put the first doc ID-->
   <doc id="docID" exclude="true" /> <!-- exclude this doc -->
 </query>`

even thought if doc is matched specifying exclude=true can eliminate that doc in the result.